# Script doesn't autorizate in strava.com

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to login in strava.com with python. I try do it (using http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRSJSKG4mDA), but i can't...

```
import requests
import bs4
with requests.Session() as c:
  url='https://strava.com/login'
  url_p='https://strava.com/session'
  Email='obichnii@yahoo.com'
  Password='12345678'
  html = c.get(url,verify=True)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text)
  loginForm = soup.find('form', {'id': 'login_form'})
  hiddenAuthKey = soup.find('input', {'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']
  print hiddenAuthKey
  login_data=dict(utf8="True",authenticity_token=hiddenAuthKey,plan='',email=Email,password=Password,remember_me='on')
  c.post(url_p,data=login_data,headers={"Referer":"https://www.strava.com/"},verify=True)
  page = c.get('https://www.strava.com/dashboard/new/web',verify=True)
  f=codecs.open('st.html','wb')
  f.write(page.content)
  f.close()
```

Comment: why you can't? which is the error that shows up?

Comment: No error. I didn't see their. 
I open st.html (page), but it = https://strava.com/login (unautorized )
If x=c.post....
Response 200

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier if, instead of using requests, you use [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> response = br.open('https://strava.com/login')
>>> br.select_form(nr=0)    # selects the first form on the login page
```

View the form's fields:

```
>>> print br.form
<POST https://www.strava.com/session application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(utf8=✓) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(authenticity_token=XgZFBcwDxCfax4AOGoDCjMYjVvM6X/iB6nSH/Cp1Um4=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(plan=) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(email=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <CheckboxControl(remember_me=[on])>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
```

Set the required values for username and password:

```
>>> br.form['email'] = 'obichnii@yahoo.com'
>>> br.form['password'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
>>> print br.form
<POST https://www.strava.com/session application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(utf8=✓) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(authenticity_token=XgZFBcwDxCfax4AOGoDCjMYjVvM6X/iB6nSH/Cp1Um4=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(plan=) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(email=obichnii@yahoo.com)>
  <PasswordControl(password=xxxxxxxx)>
  <CheckboxControl(remember_me=[on])>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
```

And submit the form:

```
>>> response = br.submit()
```

You should now be logged in...

```
>>> print br.geturl()
https://www.strava.com/dashboard/new/web
```

You can save the page to a file:

```
with open('st.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

Note also that you have posted a working login and password, you might want to change your password to prevent undesired logins.

Comment: When I choose Remember me, I found in firebug values:
 c.cookies['strava_remember_id'] 
 c.cookies['strava_remember_code']

Comment: mechanize should handle cookies for you. What is your point? Does it the mechanize method work for you or not?